# Different Group By Clause on same Query (Select/Where)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, query-optimization

Can i reuse a complex select Where clause to different group by?

What i am doing:

```
(Select X, Count(*) From [Big where clause with many tables] Group By X)
Union All
(Select Y, Count(*) From [Big where clause with many tables] Group By Y)
```

How can i optmise this?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and this will go inside a Function, but could be a stored procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WITH basequery AS (Select * From [Big where clause with many tables])
SELECT X, COUNT(*) FROM basequery GROUP BY X
UNION ALL
SELECT Y, COUNT(*) FROM basequery GROUP BY Y;
```

CTEs were made for situations like this.

Comment: @ariel Not sure whether the "optimisation" you refer to in your question is code or performance? As a performance optimisation the effect of this will be neutral. It will reuse the query definition but not the work. The CTE still gets evaluated twice  and the plan will probably be the same as your original query.

Comment: Postgres 9.2 appears to be smart enough to do the CTE only once, although (of course) it scans the temporary result twice. Other DBs, I have no real idea.

Answer (score 2):

One option you could evaluate (particularly if there are relatively few `x,y` groups) would be to materialise the intermediate results yourself into a `@table` or `#temp` table then just `SELECT` from that (a `#temp` table would be better as you could set up better indexes than the below and it allows the select query that populates it to be parallelised but these are not available in a function)

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
X int,
Y int,
Cnt int,
UNIQUE(X,Y,Cnt), /*Cnt just included to make index covering*/
UNIQUE(Y,X,Cnt)
)

INSERT INTO @T
Select X, Y, Count(*) 
From [Big where clause with many tables] 
Group By X, Y


SELECT X, SUM(Cnt)
FROM @T
GROUP BY X
UNION ALL
SELECT Y, SUM(Cnt)
FROM @T
GROUP BY Y
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2008 has introduced `GROUPING SETS ()` which seems to be just what you are after. The UNION solution suggested by others can now easily be replaced with a single select with `GROUPING SETS`.

Basically, you are using it like this:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM …
WHERE …
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (A), (B), (C) )
```

which is equivalent to

```
SELECT A, NULL, NULL, …
FROM …
WHERE …
GROUP BY A

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL, B, NULL, …
FROM …
WHERE …
GROUP BY B

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL, NULL, C, …
FROM …
WHERE …
GROUP BY C
```

So, your query might look like this:

```
SELECT X, Y, COUNT(*)
FROM your complex joins and filters
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (X), (Y) )
```

Or like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN X IS NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'X' END AS ObjType
  CASE WHEN X IS NULL THEN  Y  ELSE  X  END AS Obj,
  COUNT(*)
FROM your complex joins and filters
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (X), (Y) )
```

The second one assumes that `X` cannot be NULL.

References:

- [GROUP BY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)
- [GROUPING SETS Equivalents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510427.aspx)
- [Using GROUP BY with ROLLUP, CUBE, and GROUPING SETS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

create view

```
CREATE VIEW SomeView
AS
    Select X, Y, Count(*) AS C From [Big where clause with many tables]
```

then use the view:

```
Select X, C FROM SomeView GROUP BY X
```